# Android phone as a Samsung Smart TV remote

Tags: remote-control

I have a verizon droid 2 global and a Samsung Blu ray player that does Smart TV. I got an app to control the Blu ray player for my phone which works fine for most things but I can't do volume control.

The remote that actually came with the Blu ray player required I Configure it with the TV using the right TV manufacturers code like you would a universal remote before the volume and channel buttons with work. Can I do that with my phone?

Does my phone hardware support IR- Which I believe is what that is right? The app itself does not offer this but perhaps there's another app I can Use to set up the TV connection and then the Smart TV app's volume will just work?

Here is the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adi.remote&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dsamsung+smart+tv+app&pcampaignid=APPU_gL2HU_HjKZTNsQSY44GQCQ

I'm pretty sure it's not the app becausei even using the remote that came with the Blu ray player I had to pair the remote to the TV like a universal remote using the TV manufacturers code - is there a way I can do the same thing with my phone and the TV?

Comment: Is it OK for you if the solution would require a PC involved? I'm doing a similar job via FHEM on my Linux PC and the andFHEM app on my Android dealing with my Onkyo receiver. FHEM has a module for different Samsung SmartTVs as well, which I didn't play that much with, but should do the same for you.

Comment: What is this app you're talking about? Is it an official Samsung app, or some third-party thing? Please [edit] your question and link to it on the Google Play Store.